# WPF DataGrid won't display List<>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My DataGrid won't display anything, but my bound class contains a row of data. As you can see, my MockSnifferSource class is derived from List, which should satisfy the requirement that my collection is based on IList.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSniffer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSniffer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.DataContext>
            <local:MockSnifferSource/>
        </DataGrid.DataContext>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
public class MockSnifferSource : List<SnifferMessage>
{
    public MockSnifferSource()
    {
        Add(new SnifferMessage
        { Node = "One", Command = 1, Time = DateTime.Now, Payload = "12345", Metadata = "TTD=5" });
    }
}

public struct SnifferMessage
{ 
    public string Node;
    public byte Command;
    public DateTime Time;
    public string Payload;
    public string Metadata;                          
}
```

Can anyone identify the source of the problem?

Comment: First, don't use `List`, use `ObservableCollection`. But that's not your problem here. Your problem here is probably trying to bind to fields. You can't. `SnifferMessage` should have properties, not fields: `public string Node { get; set; }` etc. Finally, it looks like your collection is your DataContext. That's not a good idea; you'll just have to fix it later. Give your viewmodel a collection property and bind to that.

Comment: Thanks. Figured this out just before I saw the posts, silly me. Took me a while to figure out what a viewmodel was, but it was in the example below, and it worked.

Comment: Great. You should accept his answer.

Comment: It was really tough, but I used the help to figure that out too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ed Plunkett said you need to have `properties` instead of `fields` in order for binding to work

```
 public class SnifferMessage
{
    public string Node {get; set; }
    public byte Command { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Payload { get; set; }
    public string Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, I would highly suggest using the build in collection `ObservableCollection`.  This will make it so your UI reflects changes if your collection every changes.  Below is the preferred implementation

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SniffMessage}"/>


 public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SniffMessage = new ObservableCollection<SnifferMessage>();
        SniffMessage.Add(new SnifferMessage
                { Node = "one", Command = 1, Time = DateTime.Now, Payload = "1234", Metadata = "TTD" }
        );   

    }

    public ObservableCollection<SnifferMessage> SniffMessage { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I completely missed the fact that I needed properties because of being rusty, and the brilliant upgrade to ObservableCollection, which I have used before, is appreciated.